# Tag badges "re-awarded"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, badges

Yesterday I was awarded a whole bunch of tag-badges. However, *I already held them all*. It seems that I have been re-awarded all of my tag-badges for some reason, but, from what I can see, noone else has had this issue. I am wondering what has happened here?

For example, I have had the gold badge on the group-theory tag for ages. However, I was awarded this badge yesterday and, apparently, this was for the first time (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/159/group-theory?userid=10513)). At the same time, I also won the [silver](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/102/group-theory?userid=10513) and [bronze](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/group-theory?userid=10513) levels of this badge! Also, none of the [other people](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/159/group-theory) with this gold badge were awarded it yesterday, so I presume this issue is local to me.

Comment: SEDE currently shows that you were awarded this badge on 2018-02-22: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1361448/gold-tab-badges-of-the-given-user (We'll see how this changes after the next update of the data in SEDE.) Also [this snapshot from Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20200815120100/https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10513/user1729) shows you with a gold group theory badge - it is from 15 August 2020.

Comment: I had a similar experience, though it is now "day before yesterday" when it occurred.  Five bronze tag badges and two silver ones on main Math.SE.  It amounts to all my tag badges, ignoring the duplications between silver and bronze.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for doing that!! The data has been updated, and it now says the badge was awarded on "2021-01-22 04:01:29".

Comment: I noticed this too. The two tag badges I have received were both awarded yesterday. Both of these badges ([bronze combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/67/combinatorics) and [bronze matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/93/matrices)) are typically awarded once or twice a month, but both have been awarded to about a dozen users in the last week. I think I may have had these badges before; at least I haven't had any upvotes in these tags recently.

Comment: It's happening across the network, so I've posted a [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/295232) on the main Meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be resolved. Lots more details on what happened and why are available [on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/164200).