# Why have all the tags and tag-badges been removed from the user's profile page?

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page, user-profile

Today, I saw my [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210295/harish-chandra-rajpoot?tab=profile) page on stackexchange community showing that 'You have not participated in any [tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags)'. I don't know why my tags and the tag badges have been removed from my profile pages on the entire community.

Will these tags and tag-badges be re-awarded?

Could someone explain me the reason for this unexpected change in my profile page?

Comment: @Satyendra: Yes, that's why I am asking for explanation. Do you know why?

Comment: I suppose that it is related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/402142).

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33051/10513) question is related.

Comment: Some related bug reports on [meta.se]: [Tag badges are re-awarded for some users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973) and [Top \[tag\]s doesn't show anything for some users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359857)

Comment: Your tag badges are back!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thank you.