# Getting a tag badge that I already had

Tags: bug, tagging, badges, tag-management

Today, I earned the `normed-spaces` silver tag badge. And not only me: as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1063/normed-spaces), the same thing happened to two other users. The problem is that all three of us had already earned it quite some time ago. The same thing happened eight days ago with the `cubics` [bronze tag badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1059/cubics). Any idea about what's going on?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [this problem](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/tag-badges-re-awarded), which was about users getting a whole bunch of their tag badges re-awarded at the same time. Besides, that problem [was solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/402142) some time ago.

Comment: I think this is because of tag renaming (eg I renamed the tag cubic-equations to cubics; cf. [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/tag-management-2021))

Comment: In 2011, it was proposed that the [tag:norms] tag be synonymized with the [tag:normed-spaces] tag.  It was pointed out to me yesterday that the synonymization would occur with one additional vote, so I cast that vote and merged the tags.  This likely led to some tag resuffling.

Comment: It would be good if the tag badges were renamed along with the tags, but I can see that might introduce some logistical issues.

Comment: I just got a quadratic-forms   badge yesterday;  I must have had that one for a decade, mysterious.

Comment: @WillJagy The criteria for a [silver tag-badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1062/quadratic-forms) are at least 80 non-CW answers in the tag and the total score at least 400. Looking at the [top users in the tag quadratic-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/quadratic-forms/topusers), I see your name at the top with score 401. So it seems to work as expect. (Or maybe you meant something else when you described it as myseterious?)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Thanks, you got it right; I hadn't known how to check for that badge as far as years ago activity, but felt That had to be my most active tag from very early